# Como consultar un solo documento en firebase en Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firestore

En Firestore, tengo una estructura bastante simple: Coleccion "users" y dentro tiene documentos que a su vez conitenen la informacion de los usuarios, entre ellas: su UID generado por AUTH, su username, nombre y demas.
Mi pivote para poder "administrar" mis usuarios es el username, así mismo es un valor único que nuca se va a repetir.

Mi problema esta al momento de querer traer la información de ese usuario (documento) (Y si, ya me asegure que el documento y su uname en este caso sean únicos y que no se repitan en ningún otro documento; por lo que solo hay un documento por usuario). No se como hacerlo. me dieron una idea en otra pregunta, pero quedo algo atascado aun.

Una foto de la base de datos para que comprendan mejor el problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, me sugirieron traer la informacion de esta forma:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('sUid', isEqualTo: 'YOUR_UNIQUE_ID').get();
```

Escribo la linea y.... si, no marca error. Pero, ¿Que sigue?.
Como saco cada campo que tiene el documento? Ejemplo su correo y su uname.

Luego en [FluterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#read-data), vi que podia hacer esto:

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('age', isGreaterThan: 20)
  .get()
  .then(...);
```

Pero como se imaginaran, me dejo en las mismas, no se que poner en el then o que valor me puede dar la informacion.

¿Como puedo obtener la informacion del usuario?
Agradezco sus respuestas, soy nuevo en esto de Firebase y muchas cosas no las entiendo.
Gracias y tengan un buen dia.

Comment: el then tiene un parametro, si pones el cursor encima de eso te aparecerá el tipo de dato que retorna

Comment: Ok, mil gracias bro. Perdon por las preguntas tan redundates, apenas estoy introduciendome en Firebace, gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener un solo documento conociendo su ID puedes usar:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('EL ID').get()
```

Esto retorna un objeto de tipo `AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>`, el cual tiene un getter llamado `data` donde estará un mapa con los valores de este documento. En tu caso:

```
final snapshot= await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('UID').get();
```

Luego `snapshot.data` contendrá un map con keys correo, pss, y uname.
En caso de no haber conseguido un documento con ese ID, `data` será == a `null`